# Arranging XML elements from a specific response

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a specific XML response from a back-end service that looks like follow :

```html
<SubscriptionMA>
  <cDRMA>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
  </cDRMA>
  <AIRSMA>
    <c>4</c>
    <d>5</d>
  </AIRSMA>
  <PAMMA>
    <e>4</e>
  </PAMMA>
  <cDRMA>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
  </cDRMA>
  <PAMMA>
    <e>4</e>
  </PAMMA>
  <AIRSMA>
    <c>4</c>
    <d>5</d>
  </AIRSMA>
</SubscriptionMA>
```

In order to get a proper response using a the Data Mapper mediator to transform XML to Json payload, i noticed that i have to reorder the XML content like follow:

```html
<SubscriptionMA>
  <cDRMA>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
  </cDRMA>
  <cDRMA>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
  </cDRMA>
  <AIRSMA>
    <c>4</c>
    <d>5</d>
  </AIRSMA>
  <AIRSMA>
    <c>4</c>
    <d>5</d>
  </AIRSMA>
  <PAMMA>
    <e>4</e>
  </PAMMA>
  <PAMMA>
    <e>4</e>
  </PAMMA>
</SubscriptionMA>
```

Is there any solution for this please? is XSLT mediator can solve the problem and if yes, how to implement it please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide your data mapper configuration?

Comment: Here is my data mapper configuration:

Comment: I can't find it here

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this can be achieved by the Data-Mapper itself,
You have to create the mapping configuration file to get these elements in the order you prefer.

Please refer to the document [1] and create the mapping configuration from WSO2 Integration studio UI.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Data+Mapper+Mediator

Regards,

Comment: Hi there, The data mapper can not fulfill my request. In fact, when one of the arrays are duplicated, the output shows only the data of the first array encountered.

Answer (score 0):

There is my configuration

```js
map_S_subscriptionHistoryMA_S_root = function(){ 
var outputroot={};
var count_i_cDRMA = 0;
var count_i_AIRSMA = 0;
var count_i_PAMMA = 0;
outputroot =  {};
outputroot.subscriberhistory =  {};
outputroot.subscriberhistory.transactions =  {};
outputroot.subscriberhistory.transactions.transaction =  [];

for(i_cDRMA in inputsubscriptionHistoryMA.cDRMA){
outputroot.subscriberhistory.transactions.transaction[count_i_cDRMA] =  {};
outputroot.subscriberhistory.transactions.transaction[count_i_cDRMA].msisdn = inputsubscriptionHistoryMA.cDRMA[i_cDRMA].a;
outputroot.subscriberhistory.transactions.transaction[count_i_cDRMA].attr_debit = inputsubscriptionHistoryMA.cDRMA[i_cDRMA].b;

count_i_cDRMA++;
}

for(i_AIRSMA in inputsubscriptionHistoryMA.AIRSMA){
outputroot.subscriberhistory.transactions.transaction[count_i_AIRSMA] =  {};
outputroot.subscriberhistory.transactions.transaction[count_i_AIRSMA].date = inputsubscriptionHistoryMA.AIRSMA[i_AIRSMA].c;
outputroot.subscriberhistory.transactions.transaction[count_i_AIRSMA].id = inputsubscriptionHistoryMA.AIRSMA[i_AIRSMA].d;

count_i_AIRSMA++;
}

for(i_PAMMA in inputsubscriptionHistoryMA.PAMMA){
outputroot.subscriberhistory.transactions.transaction[count_i_PAMMA] =  {};
outputroot.subscriberhistory.transactions.transaction[count_i_PAMMA].msisdn = inputsubscriptionHistoryMA.PAMMA[i_PAMMA].e;

count_i_PAMMA++;
}


return outputroot;
};
```